# Retrieving data from SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data from the sqlite but then my application keeps on crashing. I don't know what is the error. I'm just a beginner in android programming .Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.the.voiceapplock;

import com.the.voiceapplock.adapter.*;
import com.the.voiceapplock.db.ProtectAppProvider;
import com.the.voiceapplock.domain.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    private ListView list;
    ArrayList<Model> data;
    ApkAdapter adapter;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    TextView tView;
    ProtectAppProvider pap;
    CheckBox chk;
    ArrayList<String> protectedApps;
    List<PackageInfo> appsList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
        appsList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        data = new ArrayList<Model>();
        for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) 
        {
            PackageInfo p = appsList.get(i);
            if (((packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(p.packageName) != null)))
            {
                Model model  = new Model();
                model.setAppName(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
                model.setAppIcon(p.applicationInfo.loadIcon((getPackageManager())));
                data.add(model);

                Collections.sort(data,Model.AppComparator);

            }
        }
        adapter = new ApkAdapter(MainActivity.this, data,packageManager,protectedApps);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
     boolean diditwork = true;
     int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
     Model obj = data.get(getPosition);
     data.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
     String apps = obj.getAppName();
     protectedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
     pap = new ProtectAppProvider(getApplicationContext());
        if(((CheckBox) buttonView).isChecked()){
            try {   
                protectedApps.add(apps);
                ProtectAppProvider entry = new ProtectAppProvider(MainActivity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(apps);
                entry.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                diditwork = false;
            }finally{
                if(diditwork){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

ApkAdapter.java

```
package com.the.voiceapplock.adapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.the.voiceapplock.MainActivity;
    import com.the.voiceapplock.R;
    import com.the.voiceapplock.db.ProtectAppProvider;
    import com.the.voiceapplock.domain.Model;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.*;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.*;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;


    public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList<Model> data;
    PackageManager p;
    ProtectAppProvider pap;
    private ArrayList<String> protectapps;

    public ApkAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> arraylist, PackageManager p, ArrayList<String> protectApps ) {
        this.ctx = c;
        this.data = arraylist;
        this.p = p;
        this.protectapps = protectApps;
        this.pap = new ProtectAppProvider(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apklist_item, parent, false);
        final CheckBox checks = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final TextView setappname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appname);
        final ImageView appicon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appicon);
        checks.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());

        Model obj = data.get(position);
        setappname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        setappname.setText(obj.getAppName());
        setappname.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        appicon.setImageDrawable(obj.getAppIcon());
        checks.setTag(position);
        checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener((MainActivity)ctx);
        String appname = "";
        pap.open();
        Cursor c = pap.getData();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                appname = c.getString(0);
                protectapps.add(appname);
            }while(c.moveToNext());

        }
        pap.close();

       return itemView;
    }

    }
```

ProtectAppProvider.java

```
package com.the.voiceapplock.db;

import android.content.*;
import android.database.*;
import android.database.sqlite.*;

public class ProtectAppProvider {

    public static final String KEY_NAME = "appName";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppLock";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "appTable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper(Context context){
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME ,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ("+KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL)" );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
    public ProtectAppProvider(Context context){
         this.context = context;
     }
    public ProtectAppProvider open() throws SQLException{
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        dbHelper.close();
    }
    public long createEntry(String apps) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, apps);
        return sqlDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
    public Cursor getData(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_NAME};
        return sqlDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    }
    }
```

LogCat
(Here's the message in the logcat)

```
 09-09 10:54:22.975: D/AbsListView(12413): Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-09 10:54:23.665: I/dalvikvm-heap(12413): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.887MB for 4194320-byte allocation
09-09 10:54:24.085: D/TextLayoutCache(12413): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-09 10:54:24.095: D/TextLayoutCache(12413): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-09 10:54:24.105: D/AndroidRuntime(12413): Shutting down VM
09-09 10:54:24.105: W/dalvikvm(12413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4184ada0)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413): Process: com.the.voiceapplock, PID: 12413
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at com.the.voiceapplock.adapter.ApkAdapter.getView(ApkAdapter.java:78)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2758)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2567)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2287)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1398)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1597)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1256)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
09-09 10:54:24.115: E/AndroidRuntime(12413):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is it crashing? where's the stack trace?

Comment: @unluddite it keeps on crashing on my device whenever I run it.

Comment: I understand, but until you provide the stack trace from logcat, you won't find much help here. How can we know where it's crashing without this information?

Comment: @unluddite how will I provide a stack trace on logcat .. sorry but I'm just a beginner

Comment: Copy your logcat messages here, so we can understand what is the problem.

Comment: You need to connect your phone to your PC and reproduce the crash within the Eclipse debugger (or on the emulator). Just Google "Android logcat tutorial."

Comment: What is the code on line 78 of ApkAdapter.java?

Comment: protectapps.add(appname); is it this one @AndrewT.?it is where the retrieval of data will be placed because i'm developing an application lock

Comment: It seems that `protectapps` is null on that line. From what I observed, when you call `adapter = new ApkAdapter(MainActivity.this, data,packageManager,protectedApps);` inside `onCreate()`, `protectedApps` is still null; it's not yet instantiated. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for your help .. it solves the issue now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logcat stacktrace,

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.the.voiceapplock.adapter.ApkAdapter.getView(ApkAdapter.java:78)
```

On line 78 of `ApkAdapter` class why it is showing `NullPointerException` because you haven't instantiated your `ArrayList` there.If you see your `MainActivity`, on line 78 you have instantiated your `ArrayList`.You will need to do something like that in your `ApkAdapter` too.

In `ApkAdapter` class, inside `getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, add this line

```
protectedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue then please accept it as a correct answer so that anyone who see this question can clearly know that this is the correct answer.